# Why attr_accessor works in module with extend self?

Tags: ruby, module

I have a basic question in ruby and i don't know why when creating a module with extend self, the attr_accessor works perfectly.

As far as i know, attr_accessor should work in an instance class, but for some reasone it's working in those modules.

Here is an example

```
module A
  extend self
  attr_accessor :custom_method

  def foo
    self.custom_method
  end
end

A.custom_method # => nil
A.foo # => nil
A.custom_method = "bar" # => "bar"
A.custom_method # => "bar"
A.foo # => "bar"
```

So, what will happen with A.custom_method? will it be "bar" accross the whole application from now?

How can i destroy this "instance" of A?

Comment: _"I have a basic question [...]"_ – `extend self` looks innocent and simple, but the result can be quite mind-boggling. To understand what's going on, it might be easier to remove that line and extend another object instead, like `obj = Object.new; obj.extend(A)`.

Comment: Do you know what `extend` does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's two contexts for the module, and the "instance" context refers to mixin methods. By calling `extend self` you're making a mixin method callable directly on the module.

```
module Example
  def mixin_level
    :mixed
  end

  def self.module_level
    :module
  end
end
```

By default you can only call these in the right context:

```
Example.module_level
# => :module

Example.mixin_level
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `mixin_level' for Example:Module
```

If you do the `extend self` trick then the `mixin_level` method, and any others in that context, will also work. You're making the module level a superset of the mixin one.

There's no way to destroy A short of removing the A constant. It's a singleton.

As a note, Rails has [`mattr_accesor`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/Module.html#method-i-mattr_accessor) which simplifies creating these without requiring `extend self`.

Comment: Excellent answer, but where is stored the data set in the attr_accessor?

Comment: As always, in whatever `self` is when that method is executed.  If this is a mixin method that some other object has called `include` on, then it goes into that object. If you're talking about `A.foo` then it goes into the A object: `A.instance_variables` via the [`instance_variables`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variables) method can be used to reflect on this.